# Connect to bitcoind from a different device within the same local network

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I have a full node running on a Linux device (A) with static IP 192.168.1.203 and I want to run bitcoin-cli commands or even eclair instances from a different device (B) within the same local network.

Device (A) has bitcoin.conf configured to accept RPC calls with this basic bitcoin.conf

```
server=1
daemon=1
txindex=1
rpcuser=<user_name>
rpcpassword=<password>
```

Actually I have an eclair running successfully on Device (A) and default RPC ports connect well. No typos on user_name and passwords.

When running the following command in device (B):

```
bitcoin-cli -rpcconnect=192.168.1.203 -rpcport=8332 -rpcuser=<user_name> -rpcpassword=<password> -getinfo


error: Could not connect to the server 192.168.1.203:8332 (error code 1 - "EOF reached")
Make sure the bitcoind server is running and that you are connecting to the correct RPC port.
```

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to just use within the network and not outside of the LAN then as mention below, use `rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0` will work and also don't use `rpcconnect` as it may cause issues. If your planning future to use that option outside of the LAN (aka WAN) then there will be security issues so make sure to not use it outside of the LAN unless you can configure it correctly to not allow accept all ip.

Comment: Futher more, according to https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/share/examples/bitcoin.conf subnet address is also supported. Therefore you can use something like `rpcallowip=192.168.0.0/24` to allow any devices with IPs from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.255

Answer (score 0):

add rpcallowip=192.168.1.203 to your bitcoin.conf and restart your daemon.
or may rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0 is your option.

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion on this with some answers here:

[Cannot call rpc api from other machine in same local network](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90996/cannot-call-rpc-api-from-other-machine-in-same-local-network)

tl;dr: you need to also set the rpcbind setting to something like rpcbind=0.0.0.0 or rpcbind='ipaddress of node'.  I needed to start the daemon with the -rpcbind=... option, it wouldn't work if I just set it in the conf file.