# Cannot call rpc api from other machine in same local network

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, regtest

### cannot call rpc api from other machine in same local network

There is a regtest node in my local network , I can call **rpc api** only from the node's machine,not my local machine.

I know `rpcallowip` is changed in recent release https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.18.0#configuration-option-changes

http clinet `httpie`

my local machine's ip: `192.168.1.155`

btc node's ip: `192.168.1.132`

the port `8332` is opened `sudo ufw allow 8332`.

## bitcoind version

```
$ bitcoind -version                 
# Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.18.0.0-g2472733a24a9364e4c6233ccd04166a26a68cc65
```

## command start bitcoind

I start regtest , and my ip is 192.168.1.155

```
bitcoind -regtest -deprecatedrpc=generate -printtoconsole -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=password -rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/24 -rpcbind=127.0.0.1  -server -rpcport=8332
```

### client request

```
# request from btc node's machine
http POST http://user:password@127.0.0.1:8332 jsonrpc="2.0" method="getblockchaininfo" id=1
# successed

# request from my local machine 192.168.1.155
http POST http://user:password@192.168.1.132:8332 jsonrpc="2.0" method="getblockchaininfo" id=1
# http: error: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.132', port=8332): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd6e288f438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)) while doing POST request to URL: http://user:password@192.168.1.132:8332/
```

Comment: `rpcbind` should probably be `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @RaghavSood `bitcoind -regtest -deprecatedrpc=generate -printtoconsole -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=password -rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/24 -rpcbind=0.0.0.0  -server -rpcport=8332` still return `Failed to establish a new connection`.

Comment: Try changing rpcallowip to `192.168.1.155`, I believe some (all?) of the RPC options don't accept netmasks

Comment: @RaghavSood  It still doesn't work. What's your bitcoind versiosn?

Comment: @ToknsitToknsit  I had a simil problem and the problem was the local network, and the example you use more modem to connect?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I try one week on it and give up .But solve it by an other way:  using a **proxy**  to request it from remote.

Comment: @RaghavSood sorry your are right , the netmask is wrong. I use `-rpcallowip=192.168.1.155 -rpcbind=127.0.0.1` in Oct 14 , It should be`-rpcallowip=192.168.1.155 -rpcbind=0.0.0.0`  from Slavik Svyrydiuk's ansower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you apply wrong options values for **-rpcallowip** and **-rpcbind**.

```
-rpcbind=127.0.0.1
```

This one tells bitcoind to bind RCP server to *127.0.0.1*(localhost). That means it will be available from the same host only.

```
-rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/24
```

0.0.0.0/24 means **Class C** network with IP address range 0.0.0.1 - 0.0.0.254

The correct options in your case are:

```
-rpcallowip=192.168.1.0/24 -rpcbind=0.0.0.0
```

or even more secure:

```
-rpcallowip=192.168.1.155 -rpcbind=192.168.1.132
```

Comment: Solved my issue. I added the 2 config values to my bitcoin.conf.  Well done answer @Slavik

Comment: Also, there is a well-documented sample bitcoin.conf file here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/share/examples/bitcoin.conf

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I create a proxy to solve it. **I am not sure if there is a risk of this code**.

https://gist.github.com/toknT/195dc5bf6d5cb6c1cb89cd424ee783bf

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const rpcPort = process.env.RPC_PORT;
const exportPort = process.env.EXPORT_PORT;

httpProxy.createProxyServer({ target: `http://127.0.0.1:${rpcPort}` }).listen(exportPort);
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer from @Slavik Svyrydiuk : it only worked for me when starting the daemon with those options (-rpcbind=0.0.0.0 -rpcallowip=192.168.1.0/24).

If I set those in the conf and just started it like normal (sudo bitcoind -daemon) then it WOULD NOT open the port to external connections.  It works only if I start the daemon with those settings like this:

`sudo bitcoind -daemon -rpcbind=0.0.0.0 -rpcallowip=192.168.1.0/24`